# Why had my `merge pull request` automatically a `merge branch`?

Tags: git, github

I had two branches `v2a-10Studio` and `improve-ocaml`. I wanted to merge `v2a-10Studio` into `improve-ocaml`, and made a pull request in the website of GitHub. But after that, I realized that there is one commit `Merge branch 'improve-ocaml' into v2a-10Studio` generated almost at the same time. I don't remember I did this.

Did I accidentally click something? Does merging a pull request always imply a merging branch?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Were you expecting the `v2a-10Studio` branch to _fast-forward_ the `improve-ocaml` branch?

Comment: I wanted to keep `v2a-10Studio` as it was; I wanted `improve-ocaml` to get all the latest change of `v2a-10Studio`.

Comment: According to the doc https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/merging-a-pull-request, pull requests are merged with `--no-ff`, except for pull requests with squashed or rebased commits, which means there is always a merge commit like `Merge branch 'improve-ocaml' into v2a-10Studio` in your case. It's automatically created as expected.

Comment: Cool, could you add an answer so that I could accept? @ElpieKay